# How to get caffe notebook example

Tags: caffe

I see many blogs relate caffe something about notebook example? I only find "example " dir in the caffe source code on github, how to get the "notebook example" dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `notebook` they mean to say `ipython notebook`. Details of ipython notebook can be found [here](http://ipython.org/notebook.html).

The file format of ipython notebook is `.ipynb`. The files with this extension can be found in the `examples` folder.

If the ipython notebook is successfully installed, you can try running the `01-learning-lenet.ipynb` example by typing : `ipython notebook ./examples/01-learning-lenet.ipynb` from the caffe folder.

Comment: thany you, I will try it!

Comment: I mark it as the answer, however my level is so low that I can't upvote your answer.